# Why is entity &eacute; not valid whereas entity &lt; is?

Tags: c#, dtd, xmlreader

I'm looking at what the xml resolver `System.Xml.Resolvers.XmlPreloadedResolver` brings to the table in terms of dtds and i'm stumped by the fact that the entity `&lt;` is recognized by the xml reader but not the entity `&eacute;`.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string invalidContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><key value=\"char &eacute; invalid\"/>";
        string validContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><key value=\"char &lt; valid\"/>";

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings()
        {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
            XmlResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver(XmlKnownDtds.All),
            ProhibitDtd = false
        };

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(invalidContent), xmlReaderSettings))
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(reader); // reference to undeclared entity 'eacute'
        }

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(validContent), xmlReaderSettings))
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(reader); //
        }
    }
```

Checking inside the XmlPreloadedResolver i can see that the `XmlKnownDtds.All` should bring in the xhtml-lat1.ent file which contains the eacute entity, along with many others. Any idea why i'm seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&lt;` is a fundamental entity defined in the XML specification itself; `&eacute;` isn't. That's why you're seeing the difference in behaviour. (So I'd expect `&amp;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;` to work too.) See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references

I don't *think* the `XmlResolver` is particularly relevant here as your XML doesn't refer to any other DTDs etc. I don't think it's meant to be used to *automatically* import entities without referring to anything at all within the document itself.

Comment: In hindsight, sounds completely logical; but what happened is that i took the content of a working web.config file and decided to feed it into an xml reader. That's when the error about the eacute entity appeared. So the new question now is "What happens during the reading of web.config to let this entity go through?".

Comment: Either that file refers to an external DTD (or includes an embedded DTD that contains an entity declaration for `&eacute;`) or that file is read as HTML instead of XML, which works because HTML has definitions for several entities like `&eacute;`.