# What does the ConfigurationManager use to load *.config files?

Tags: c#, configuration, xmlreader

After asking [why the XmlReader was refusing to recognize the `&eacute;` html entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301879/why-is-entity-eacute-not-valid-whereas-entity-lt-is) (and the subsequent to-the-point Jon Skeet answer), I realized that the .net ConfigurationManager is able to load "invalid" configuration files; the following app.config file is invalid for the `XmlReader` but can be accessed with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["invalid"]`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="invalid" value="this is invalid &eacute; "/>
    <add key="valid" value="this is valid &lt;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

An interesting point is that if your app.config contains the `&eacute;` entity Visual Studio underlines it and warns you that it is invalid.

I tried peeking under the curtain into `ConfigurationManager` with ILSpy but couldn't get a handle on where it was going; it cannot be `XmlReader` (or if it is there is some non-trivial xml setup before the file is loaded) but what's the deal with this class? What does ConfigurationManager use to load *.config files?